# Sending large image file's binary data over TCP sockets

Tags: python, file, sockets, while-loop, binary

I'm trying to send an image's binary data from the server (after I opened the image file as 'rb') to the client:

This is the `server-side`: sending the image binary data in pieces to the client:

```
BUFSIZ = 262144 #max tcp length

while len(pic_data) > BUFSIZ:
    client.send(pic_data[:BUFSIZ])
    print len(pic_data[:BUFSIZ])
    pic_data = pic_data[BUFSIZ:]
if len(pic_data) <= BUFSIZ:
    client.send(pic_data)
    print len(pic_data)
client.send("alldone") #telling the client he finished
```

The `client-side` is receiving the info in pieces and saving the whole binary data as a file on the computer:

```
pic_data = ""
r = client_socket.recv(BUFSIZ)
while r != "alldone":
    pic_data += r
    r = client_socket.recv(BUFSIZ)
    print len(r)
    print str(questions_data[count][0])
 print len(pic_data)

if r == "alldone":
    filepath = "C:\Users\hilab\PycharmProjects\dafyProject\\pic" + str(questions_data[count][0]) + 
    ".jpg"
    with open(filepath, 'wb') as file:
        file.write(pic_data)
```

- questions_data[count][0] grows +1 for every image that's sent

However, if an image's binary-data length is more than `BUFSIZ` (262144), the image isn't successfully saved and the program gets stuck.

I suspect that somehow the `'alldone'` message is added to the `pic_data` variable (cause I've noticed that if I change the final message from 'alldone' to a message with different length - the length of the last piece of the image binary-data that's accepted by the client changes as well)

Do you know what the problem is? how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

messages sent using tcp might be added or split in the sending process. What I would do is add to each message its length at the beginning (8 digits will defiantly do if you want to be safe, it must be constant though). On the client-side, you will have to first receive a message in the length of 8, interpret the size of the incoming message, and then use the recv() function with the length you just read. That way you can make sure each message is received fully and wasn't added to another message.

Comment: Thanks! could you please demonstrate how to do that? I just tried and I got this error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'alldone' @amityakovian

Comment: it means you were trying to use the int() function on the string "alldone". you have to send the length of "alldone" in the beginning as well :)
If you're still having trouble with this let me know